# LDAP authentication using scala or java

Tags: java, scala, ldap

I've created a LDAP server on my machine and created one user as admin inside LDAP server and  I can access it with the URL say
`http://192.158.2.136/phpldapadmin`, now I've a login page in my application and what I want is when someone enters username and password I want my application to validate this user from LDAP server i.e I should check whatever username and password is entered same exists in LDAP server or not.So far I tried with `apacheds-all` but couldn't find a proper way to send username and password to server, can someone please tell me how to do this in `java` or `scala`, I should be able to validate the user credentials from LDAP server using `java` or `scala` as client code.Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a solution finally :

```
 object LDAPValidations {

    def validateForLDAP(username: String, passcode: String): Boolean = {

    val result = Try {
      var props = new Properties
      props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory")
      props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.1.121:389")
      props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, s"cn=$username,cn=staff,dc=myreutore,dc=local")
      props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "administrator")

      var context: InitialDirContext = new InitialDirContext(props)

      val controls: SearchControls = new SearchControls
      controls.setReturningAttributes(Array[String]("givenName", "sn", "memberOf", "cn"))
      controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE)

      val answers: NamingEnumeration[SearchResult] = context.search("dc=myrtor,dc=local", s"cn=$username", controls)
      val result: SearchResult = answers.nextElement

      val user: String = result.getNameInNamespace
      props = new Properties
      props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory")
      props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.1.121:389")
      props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user)
      props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, passcode)
      context = new InitialDirContext(props)
    }
    result match {
      case Success(v) => true
      case Failure(v) => false
    }

  }

}
```